# Update one record using entity frame work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, insert-update

I wanna update one record to database using entity framework . when update this record all date for this employee set Null Only Employee Code And IsActive .. how update isAcive only

this is My Code

```
       private void btn_Save_Resignation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          try
           {
                   var IsActive = new database.tblEmployeeData
                   {

                       EmployeeCode = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmpCode.Text),
                       IsActive = cbxResignationEmp.Checked = true, 
                   };


                       db.tblEmployeeDatas.AddOrUpdate(IsActive);
                       db.SaveChanges();
                       MessageBox.Show("تم إقالة الموظف بنجاح", "Sigma Software", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                       ClearResignation();

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Sigma Software", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
           }
}
```

.................
This is my model class

```
   public partial class tblEmployeeData
   {
       [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
       public tblEmployeeData()
       {
           this.tblBlackListForEmps = new HashSet<tblBlackListForEmp>();
           this.tblContractForEmploees = new HashSet<tblContractForEmploee>();
           this.tblCustodyForEmps = new HashSet<tblCustodyForEmp>();
           this.tblDocumentEmployeeWithStates = new HashSet<tblDocumentEmployeeWithState>();
           this.tblOtherDataForEmps = new HashSet<tblOtherDataForEmp>();
           this.tblPenaltyForEmployees = new HashSet<tblPenaltyForEmployee>();
       }

       public int EmployeeCode { get; set; }
       public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
       public Nullable<byte> GenderCode { get; set; }
       public Nullable<byte> PranchCode { get; set; }
       public Nullable<byte> RelationShipCode { get; set; }
       public Nullable<byte> AdministrationCode { get; set; }
       public Nullable<byte> DepartmentCode { get; set; }
       public Nullable<short> JopCode { get; set; }
       public Nullable<byte> JopLevelCode { get; set; }
       public Nullable<byte> ConCustmerCode { get; set; }
       public Nullable<byte> NationalityCode { get; set; }
       public Nullable<byte> TypeOfWorkersCode { get; set; }
       public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
```

Comment: If you want to update record, you should use the record existing in the database rather then inserting a new one.

Comment: First Find your record, then change it, and set it as modified then save changes -HTH ;).

Comment: Also take a look: https://www.michaelgmccarthy.com/2016/08/24/entity-framework-addorupdate-is-a-destructive-operation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://www.michaelgmccarthy.com/2016/08/24/entity-framework-addorupdate-is-a-destructive-operation/):

> Entity Framework does not magically figure out which properties have
>   changed vs. which properties have not changed, it takes the entity,
>   and if it exists, enters the entity into the database as it’s
>   currently populated. If the entity does not exist, it inserts it into
>   the database.

So I would recommend you to change your code in the next way:

```
var empCode = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmpCode.Text);
var IsActive = db.tblEmployeeDatas.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeCode == empCode);
if (IsActive == null)
{
   IsActive = new database.tblEmployeeData
   {
      EmployeeCode = empCode,
   };
}
IsActive.IsActive = cbxResignationEmp.Checked = true, // BTW should it be assigning or condition?

db.tblEmployeeDatas.AddOrUpdate(IsActive);
db.SaveChanges();
...
```